# Swift Long press results

Tags: objective-c, swift, long-press, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I would like to intercept the value of the long press of this pod :

https://github.com/liyong03/YLLongTapShare

[image]

I am developing in Swift and this pod is only Objective-C.

I don't manage to catch the func that handle the end of the selection of the long press (here, on the screenshot), I would like to retrieve "**Twitter**" once the user has release the long press (and his choice was Twitter)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You mean that you didn't understood how to set the delegate method `longTapShareView:didSelectShareTo:withIndex:` or the closure `SelectedHandler`?

Comment: Hello Larme, glad to see your post again ! Yes, I think I don't know how to handle this with swift .

Comment: To be more precise, I would like to intercept for example the  func touchesEnded

 func touchesEnded { 
print ("index value or item value \(index) or \(item.text)") //--> should capture "Twitter"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In pod file uncomment use_frameworks! line, update pod, then build project
2. Import 'YLLongTapShare' module in view controller
3. Write rest of code:)

Simple example:

```
import UIKit
import YLLongTapShare
class TestViewController: UIViewController, YLLongTapShareDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tapShareView: YLLongTapShareView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tapShareView.delegate = self;
    self.tapShareView.add(YLShareItem(icon: UIImage(named: "test1"), andTitle: "test1"))
    self.tapShareView.add(YLShareItem(icon: UIImage(named: "test2"), andTitle: "test2"))
    self.tapShareView.add(YLShareItem(icon: UIImage(named: "test3"), andTitle: "test3"))
}

func longTapShare(_ view: UIView!, didSelectShareTo item: YLShareItem!, with index: UInt) {
    print("longTapShare \(item.title)")
}

func colorOfShareView() -> UIColor! {
    return UIColor.red
}

}
```

Comment: Hello Piotr Golinski, thanks for the answer. It works !
Have a nice day!